# Get duplicate records that match 2 IDs but include all from 3rd ID

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hi I have an MS Access/SQL query question. I have a table

```
ID1     ID2      ID3
 1       1        4
 2       2        5
 1       1        1
 3       1        2
 1       1        3
```

I want these results:

```
ID1    ID2       ID3
 1      1         4
 1      1         1
 1      1         3
```

I want all the records that duplicates when ID3 = 4 but I want the other ID3 values to show. Any records from ID3 = 4 that matches records from the other ID3.

I tried looking up other examples like retrieving states that share the same city names. But I have multiple matches I need, so it would be like retrieving states that share the same count and city names. Any suggestions? I can find the duplicates but I only want the duplicates where ID3 = 4.

Comment: What if there are no duplicates? Do you want only the row with id3 = 4?

Comment: No, only where there are duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this query:

```
SELECT id1, id2
FROM tablename
GROUP BY id1, id2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND SUM(IIF(id3 = 4, 1, 0)) > 0
```

to identify if `id1` and `id2` of `id3 = 4` have any duplicates, so join it to the table:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM tablename AS t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id1, id2
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY id1, id2
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND SUM(IIF(id3 = 4, 1, 0)) > 0
)  AS tt ON tt.id1 = t.id1 AND tt.id2 = t.id2
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t as t2
              where t2.id1 = t.id1 and
                    t2.id2 = t.id2 and
                    t2.id3 = 4
             );
```